# How to get the brother DOMNode from DOMElement php scraping?

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument

I'm working with PHP, and I'm try to scrapping a I little chunck of code, but in this moment I don't know how. The following is the simple structure that I can't scrap, the text inside of double quotes.

```html
<strong>Palabras: </strong>
<br>            
"   
     Biometría,          
     Análisis de textura,                    
     Wavelets,        
     Codificación predictiva,  
     Reconocimiento de patrones,                      
     Filtros Bidimensionales de Gabor, 
"                   
<br>
```

The original text is [here](http://scienti1.colciencias.gov.co:8081/cvlac/visualizador/generarCurriculoCv.do?cod_rh=0000473472#articulos):

```html
Producción bibliográfica - Artículo - Publicado en revista especializada
some name,another name, "E-Learning y Espacios Colaborativos" . En: CountryName
ISSN: ed:
v. fasc. p. - ,2006 
Palabras: 
E-learning, Espacios Colaborativos, 
Sectores: 
Educación,
```

This is my attemp to scrap the text inside of double quotations

```php
 //getting Palabras text content
  $list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('strong');
  foreach($list as $node)
  {
      if( $node->nodeValue == "Palabras: " )
      {
         //what can I do here to get the double quotations content
      }
  }
```

If the comparison is true  `$node->nodeValue == "Palabras: "` I try to get the content with the "brother" node like this:

```php
if( $node->nodeValue == "Palabras: " )
{
    $nodeValue = $node->nextSibling->nodeValue;
}
```

But if I try to do it, I get a error in which the problem is that the `$node->nextSibling` is a `DOMElement`, for this reason the  `$node->nextSibling` hasen't the attribute `nodeValue`.

So how can I do to get the "brother" `DOMNode` ?

**Note:**

why I not call the `$doc->getElementsByTagName('br')` instead `$doc->getElementsByTagName('strong')` because there are a lot of `br` tags in the web page but I just need the text after  `<strong>Palabras: </strong>`(this is the only tags to identify the text content inside of  double quotation ) and I don't planned find the `br` tag between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression to find `<strong>Palabras: </strong>` then the first following sibling text node that doesn't consist entirely of whitespace.

---

#### Example:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//strong[.="Palabras: "]/following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()][1]';

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: not works, I've the following mistake `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: could you explain me, what was the problem to get right the content?, and what tool you used to build the `xpath query`